# Trying to create a batch file to move and replace desktop.ini but it say file cannot be found

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My code is:

```
cd "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Post-Install\Icon Config Files\"

move /y "Games\desktop.ini" "%UserProfile%\Games"
move /y "Music\desktop.ini" "%UserProfile%\Music"
move /y "Personal Docs\desktop.ini" "%UserProfile%\Personal Docs"
move /y "Pictures\desktop.ini" "%UserProfile%\Pictures"
move /y "Software\desktop.ini" "%UserProfile%\Software"
move /y "User\desktop.ini" "%UserProfile%"
move /y "Videos\desktop.ini" "%UserProfile%\Videos"

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

start explorer.exe
```

However, every time I run this, its telling me "The system cannot find the file specified". What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Description of tag `dos`: "A family of text-based operating systems for IBM PCs and compatibles of the 1980s and 1990s, including MS-DOS. DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR QUESTIONS ABOUT THE WINDOWS COMMAND PROMPT! "

Comment: Oh, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*desktop.ini* files are hidden, that's why the `move` command cannot find them. So before every move remove the hidden (and system, it has to be both) attributes with `attrib -s -h "Games\desktop.ini"`, and after every move restore these attributes with `attrib +s +h "%UserProfile%\Games\desktop.ini"`